# Makefile variables not working as expected

Tags: c++, makefile, kernel, gnu-make

I am trying to compile a program using this makefile:

```
GCCPARAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -nostdlib -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32

objects = src/loader.o src/kernel.o

%.o: src/%.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPARAMS) -c -o $@ $<

%.o: src/%.s
    echo $(ASPARAMS)
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

kernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: kernel.bin
    sudo cp $< boot/mykernel.bin
```

The problem comes when doing `make` which prints the following:

```sh
as   -o src/loader.o src/loader.s
src/loader.s: Assembler messages:
src/loader.s: Warning: end of file not at end of a line; newline inserted
src/loader.s:18: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
src/loader.s:19: Error: operand type mismatch for `push'
make: *** [<builtin>: src/loader.o] Error 1
```

As you can se the variable is not properly set, instead, `make` puts a space where the variable should be. That causes the assembler compiler to think it's a 64 bit architecture and giving some errors.

Any idea of what is going on? I am doing this using WSL2 by the way.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see this is because your recipe rules are wrong.

You have these object files:

```
objects = src/loader.o src/kernel.o
```

and you have this rule:

```
%.o: src/%.s
        echo $(ASPARAMS)
        as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<
```

When trying to build `src/loader.o` what does the stem of the pattern `%.o` match?  It will match `src/loader` of course.  So then what will the prerequisite be?  It will be `src/%.s` with the stem expanded, so it will be `src/src/loader.s`.  I presume that this doesn't exist.

As a result of this, this pattern rule doesn't match.  So what does make do?  It looks for a different pattern rule, and it turns out that GNU make provides a default pattern rule to build a `.s` file, which uses a pattern `%.o : %.s` and that pattern DOES match, so that's used.

But that built-in rule uses the standard make variables, which are `AS` and `ASFLAGS`.  You haven't set `ASFLAGS`, so no flags are used.

You can tell that it's not using your rule because your rule has an `echo ...` in it and make does not print that command out.  Therefore, it's not running your rule.